# Spring controller is not hitting. Going to error block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to hit the controller from my JSP Page. I had written the following function which will be called on the click of the particular link.

The function implementation is been shown below:

```
function categorySearchBasedOnParentId(name,id){
        $.ajax({
                url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/get_categoriesByParentId.shx",
                data: 'id='+id,
                success:function(data){
                    var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var obj2 = obj1.tempCategoriesList;
                    $("#subCategoriesFilter").html(buildSub(obj2));
                },
                error:function(data,status,err){
                    alert("Error occured while searching the categories based on the parent category id");
                }
        });
```

In the above function i am trying to hit controller url and the controller is returning back the JSON object.I am converting the JSON to JavaScript object and iterating it's value to display in the particular div tag.

The controller which i had written in the spring is as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/get_categoriesByParentId.shx",method = RequestMethod.GET,    headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody String getCategoriesByParentId(Model model,HttpSession session,
        @ModelAttribute("shoppingCart") ShoppingCart shoppingCart,
        @RequestParam("id") String id) throws IOException{
        shoppingCart.setTempCategoriesList(categoryDao.getAllCategoriesByParentCategoryId(id));
        model.addAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart); 
        String json = JSONUtil.createJsonString(shoppingCart);
        System.out.println(json);
        return json;
    }
```

I had done the following test:
1)The value is been passed properly to the function. I had alerted and seen. 
2)The same controller call can be done in the other project. It is returning the JSON object.

I am getting following error on the console infinite time.

```
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
```

I had almost wasted my whole day on this. I want help. Please help me.

Comment: Can you try removing @ModelAttribute("shoppingCart") ShoppingCart shoppingCart as argument and see if its hitting the controller? Since you are doing GET, i am wondering @ModelAttribute("shoppingCart") is not being passed in.

Comment: @minion : I need shoppingCart object value's, so i can't remove it. I have to convert it into JSON and send it to the view i.e; jsp page. I am getting the following error on console                                                       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)

Comment: Where are you getting shoppingCart  from? Some function has to pass it rite. Also provide complete stack trace.

Comment: @minion: I am storing the value of the shoppingCart is the previous functions using it setter's method. Like this then add it to the model attribute as shown below         shoppingCart.setCategories(categoryManager.getCategories(categoryType));
   shoppingCart.setCategoriesMap(categoryManager.getCategoriesMap(categoryType));
   model.addAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart);

Comment: Can you post the previous function? How is the previous function being invoked in spring flow?

Comment: @minion:@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/get_subcategories.shx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getSubCategories(Model model, HttpSession session,
   @ModelAttribute("shoppingCart") ShoppingCart shoppingCart,
   @RequestParam("parentCategoryId") Integer parentCategoryId) throws IOException{
  for(Category category : shoppingCart.getCategoriesMap().keySet()){
   if(category.getId()==parentCategoryId){
    return JSONUtil.createJsonString(shoppingCart.getCategoriesMap().get(category));
   }
  }
  model.addAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart); 
  return null;
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71508/discussion-between-minion-and-rahul-sah).

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your controller with @RestController and return your shopping cart. Spring will convert it to JSON.

If you want to change the converter, you have to configure Spring for that, but it should work out-of-the-box for common use cases.